# Advantages of Comet software over standard Long Polling

Tags: php, long-polling

I cannot figure out for the life of me the purpose of an application like Cometd or simple-comet over something like a simple longpolling request with php and an infinite loop with code like so

```
$time = time();
while(time() - $time < 30) {
    if ($query) {
        $shapes = ...;
        echo json_encode($shapes);
        break;
    }
    usleep(25000);
}
```

running on a webserver that is designed for multiple requests, like lighttpd or NGIX.

maybe I am just miss understanding the documentation of comet services.  I know the above is a "Comet" request but why do things like cometd exist, what do they do better.

Comment: For one, there's no 250 ms delay between responses as you would have in your example.  Also, you don't have to have a whole separate PHP process for every active connection.  Those things are pretty heavy.  You should be able to have a lot more comet connections open per server than you'd be able to have with the equivalent PHP long polling solution.

Comment: @frank apache is the only webserver that leaves a thread for each connection.  lighttpd is actually designed to multithread connections.

Comment: PHP itself isn't really thread-safe, though -- certainly, many PECL modules aren't.  With lighttpd/nginx, don't you end up with a PHP CGI proc running for every active connection?

Comment: @Frank from what I have read no I will try to add some sources to my Question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cometd and similar software like orbitd are great for breaking up area's of responsibility.  I can have my lighttpd backed python services focus on doing more involved work while the comet service is tied to a message queue to handle light message notifications (ex batch request is finished, you've got a new message, etc ) while the lighttpd servers handle DB requests or process POST/PUT/DELETE requests.

Last point, Apache is still a very popular web server but it will die in a blaze of glory if it tries to hold a thousand or more connections open.  For a platform with an array of apache servers that wants to add comet support, it would make sense to go with an out of the box solution versus rolling one with lighttpd or nginx.